# Getting Chrome to trust certificate in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, chrome, certificates

So, this is something I have done before (I swear!)... but I am struggling with for whatever reason. I would like to import a certificate (.der) so that Chrome will not warn/block me from accessing HTTPS sites that use it.

I have successfully imported the certificate into IceWeasel with no problems. So, that means that the cert itself is fine (right?).

Some of the things I have tried to get it to work with Chrome are:

putting the cert in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and running `sudo update-ca-certificates`. Note that I converted the file to a `pem` file first by doing the following: `openssl x509 -inform der -in cacert.der -out cacert.pem`. `update-ca-certificates` didn't pick up the pem file, so I renamed it to a `crt` file. It seemed to read the file in and successfully import it. I have verified that the certificate is inside `/etc/ssl/certs` as `cacert.pem`.

I have also tried simply manually importing various formats of the certificate through Chromium's UI, but **nothing** is working. Does anyone have the de-facto repeatable way of importing a root ca in Kali/Debian so that it can be used by Chromium/Chrome?

Note that while I am using Kali, I am not currently running as the root user (which is fairly common). Not sure if this is important, but I figured it is worth mentioning.

Just in case it matters: uname-a => `Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-7kali2 (2016-01-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I know for a fact it is possible, at least in Kali 2, because I have a VM running where I have successfully done it.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the flag called `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost`
from :

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Click enable:

> Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost. Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
>   Allows requests to localhost over HTTPS even when an invalid certificate is presented. #allow-insecure-localhost
>
> **Enable**

Comment: This wouldn't help me because I need to essentially MitM all http/https requests to sites on the Internet. I'm using BurpSuite Proxy.